# behavior of classmethods and static variables in pythone

Tags: python, inheritance, class-method, static-variables

Suppose I have the following classes

```
class Parent: 
    message = "Hello World"
    @classmethod
    def print_message(cls):
        print(cls.message)
    @classmethod 
    def change_message(cls, new_message):
            cls.message =  new_message

class Child_one(Parent):
    @classmethod 
    def print_messsage(cls):
        print (cls.message)
    @classmethod 
    def change_message(cls, new_message):
        cls.message = new_message

class Child_two(Parent):
    @classmethod
    def print_message(cls):
        print(cls.message)
```

I suppose my question is to what does the `cls` of child classes refer to, because If I change the static variable `message` in parent class it rightly changes values of the of `message` in both children

```
Parent.change_message("This is new message")
Child_one.print_message() # This is new message 
Child_two.print_message() # This is new message
```

this is my expected behavior, both of the `cls.message` refer to the message of parent class. However doing this

```
Child_one.change_message("I am child one")
```

results in behavior such as

```
Parent.print_message() # This is new message 
Child_one.print_message() # I am child one 
Child_two.print_message() # This is new message
```

So the `cls.message` variable of Child_one no longer points to the message of the parent class.

In other langues such as `c++` or `c#` static changing a static variable of a parent class or a child class results in change in all of the parent and derived classes. Is there a way to duplicate this behavior in `python` and if not why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frank-Rene's answer is absolutely correct, and you can see this behavior by observing the memory addresses of the class variable:

```
print(Parent.message, Child_one.message) #identical memory addresses
Child_one.change_message("something")
print(Parent.message, Child_one.message) #now they are different
```

This is because each class in Python keeps its attributes in a dunder dictionary (`__dict__`), and if they are not overriden they will reference the parent until modified.

For your use case, you might be interested in Python's borg design pattern: https://github.com/faif/python-patterns/blob/master/patterns/creational/borg.py

Answer (score 1):

**Upon Write**:

As soon as you assign a something to a member of a class or object while this member does not exist by name, it is created.

The fact, that a member's name is present in the base class does not change anything. It is created in the class itself.

**Upon Read**:

The name resolution goes then: First try to find a member in the class itself, then in its base classes.

Comment: I understand that, however I don't understand why does python create a new member for `Child_one` when I set it. It doesn't exist for the `Child_one`, but since it's a derived class shouldn't it check if it's parent class has a member called `message` and only then decide to create it? Doesn't  ignoring parent classes upon write violate the **is a** relationship